# Sum column tabulator based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to sum column value in tabulator with specific condition and follow this [Custom Calculation Function](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/column-calcs#func-builtin)

What I tried so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  var adultCalc = function(values, data, calcParams) {
    var tempvalue = [];
    
    data.forEach(function(data) {
      var count = data.age * data.qty;
      tempvalue.push(count);
    });

    console.log('array', tempvalue);
    console.log('total', tempvalue.reduce(getSum));
    
    /*return tempvalue;*/
  }


  var tabledata = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Oli Bob",
      age: "12",
      qty: "1",
      dob: ""
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Christine Lobowski",
      age: "42",
      qty: "1",
      dob: "22/05/1982"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Brendon Philips",
      age: "35",
      qty: "2",
      dob: "01/08/1980"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Margret Marmajuke",
      age: "16",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "31/01/1999"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Marmajuke",
      age: "17",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "31/01/1999"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Philips",
      age: "27",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "01/08/1980"
    }
  ];

  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205,
    data: tabledata,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        field: "age",
        bottomCalc: adultCalc
      },
      {
        title: "Qty",
        field: "qty"
      },
      {
        title: "Date Of Birth",
        field: "dob",
        sorter: "date",
        align: "center"
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

My formula is : `age * qty` push it into array and total it.

I'm success to get the value what i want and push it into array, but the problem is i can't sum the array with [array reduce function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp).

I got this error

> TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value

My problem just to get total sum of array.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide initial value to reduce

```
console.log('total', tempvalue.reduce(getSum,0));
```

first time when you use reduce you have an empty array and which is causing reduce to produce an error. you can pass initial value and it should work as expected.

> Note: If initialValue isn't provided, reduce() will execute the
>   callback function starting at index 1, skipping the first index. If
>   initialValue is provided, it will start at index 0.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  var adultCalc = function(values, data, calcParams) {
    var tempvalue = [];
    
    data.forEach(function(data) {
      var count = data.age * data.qty;
      tempvalue.push(count);
    });

    console.log('array', tempvalue);
    console.log('total', tempvalue.reduce(getSum,0));
    
    /*return tempvalue;*/
  }


  var tabledata = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Oli Bob",
      age: "12",
      qty: "1",
      dob: ""
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Christine Lobowski",
      age: "42",
      qty: "1",
      dob: "22/05/1982"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Brendon Philips",
      age: "35",
      qty: "2",
      dob: "01/08/1980"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Margret Marmajuke",
      age: "16",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "31/01/1999"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Marmajuke",
      age: "17",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "31/01/1999"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Philips",
      age: "27",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "01/08/1980"
    }
  ];

  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205,
    data: tabledata,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        field: "age",
        bottomCalc: adultCalc
      },
      {
        title: "Qty",
        field: "qty"
      },
      {
        title: "Date Of Birth",
        field: "dob",
        sorter: "date",
        align: "center"
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: can you tell me from where the `0` comes? and why `0` sir?

Comment: @illuminarch when you run my snippet you will see array[] empty and then it gets the values.

Comment: yap when i running in my local machine too, i see the empty array, but i think it should reduce the last array with values not first (the empty arrays).  in this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the initial index provide with `5`. i am still confuse where `0` or `5` comes.

Comment: @illuminarch you read it wrongly, its not initial index its initial value. 5 as initial value. so, 5+1+2+3+4 = 15 as an output.

Comment: oh okay sir, i got this clearly. so why the initial value `5` cause its in first queue. thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Btw already solve this problem with other ways but your answer give me more information and this will be accepted aswer. thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done even easier. And don't forget the second parameter (initial value) of `Array.reduce` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  var adultCalc = function(values, data, calcParams) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
        return d.age * d.qty;
      })
      .reduce(getSum, 0);
  }
  //or even in ES6 style
  const qtyCalc = (values, data, calcParams) => 
     data.map(d => d.age * d.qty)
      .reduce((t, n) => t + n * 2, 0);
  

  var tabledata = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Oli Bob",
      age: "12",
      qty: "1",
      dob: ""
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Christine Lobowski",
      age: "42",
      qty: "1",
      dob: "22/05/1982"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Brendon Philips",
      age: "35",
      qty: "2",
      dob: "01/08/1980"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Margret Marmajuke",
      age: "16",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "31/01/1999"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Marmajuke",
      age: "17",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "31/01/1999"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Philips",
      age: "27",
      qty: "0",
      dob: "01/08/1980"
    }
  ];

  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205,
    data: tabledata,
    layout: "fitColumns",
    columns: [{
        title: "Name",
        field: "name",
        width: 150
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        field: "age",
        bottomCalc: adultCalc
      },
      {
        title: "Qty",
        field: "qty",
        bottomCalc: qtyCalc
      },
      {
        title: "Date Of Birth",
        field: "dob",
        sorter: "date",
        align: "center"
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```